# Updating a mobile-app (phonegap) when new calendar events have been added

Tags: cordova

I Have a phonegap app that need to updated whenever a new calendar event has been added / deleted.

Is this possible without a service ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use (at least for iOS it works quit well) this [plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin). You can read and modify events in your calendar there. So you could check on each startup of your application if the event you created has been changed (e.g. by storing the creation properties in the `localStorage` and comparing them).

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Not quite what I am after. I would like that a calender event will trigger my app.

Comment: So you want to start your app whenever a calendar event is changed? Really? I think i would uninstall any application which does something like that. But if you really want to do that, then you have to write a service for your platforms, listen on calendar entry changes and then open your application each time such an event changes...